# Calling Doctrine from custom class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

/*Edited*/

I have this class:

```
namespace Baza\BlogBundle\Form;   
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager; 

class filterType extends AbstractType
{

  protected $em;
  public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
 {
     $this->em = $em;
 }
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

   $this->$em->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

   /****
   ****/

 }
}
```

And this is my services yml:

```
services:
 filterType:
    class: Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType
    arguments: [doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

When I run the code I get following exception:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given

I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Try: `arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]` Added the `@`, not sure what it means but all my Symfony code uses it.

Comment: I tried it, I get: "ScannerException while scanning for the next token we had this found character @(64) that cannot start any token" in editor.

Comment: Be sure you are have correct number of spaces.

Comment: Why you are adding `Form` type as __Doctrine__ `prePersist` ?

Comment: I was trying something, I'm pretty sure that's not causing the error here.

Comment: +1 for Artern as to why you are using an AbstractType as a doctrine event listener.  You're also missing your second argument in the service definition for AppKernel.  Additionally, why are you attempting to pass AppKernel as a service definition?

Comment: I edited code according to your remarks. The same error still persists.

Comment: `$this->$em->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()` should be `$this->em`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created the FormType myself. This should work:

```
<?php
// Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType.php

namespace Baza\BlogBundle\Form;  

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class filterType extends AbstractType
{
  protected $em;

  public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
  {
     $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    // Do something with your Entity Manager using "$this->em"
  }

  public function getName()
  {
      return 'filter_type';
  }
}
```

In your Controller use something like

```
<?php
// Baza\BlogBundle\Controller\PageController.php

namespace Baza\BlogBundle\Controller;
use Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
     public function testEntityManager()
     {
         // assign whatever you need
         $enquiry = null;
         // getEntityManager() is depricated. Use getManager() instead.
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

         $this->createForm(
             new filterType($em),
             $enquiry
         );
     } 
}
```

**Never forget to include/use all the classes you are using. Otherwise PHP will assume the class is inside your currently used namespace.**

That's why you got the error (on Cerad's post)

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType::__construct()
must be an instance of Baza\BlogBundle\Form\EntityManager [...]
```

As you didn't include the EntityManager PHP assumes it's a class inside your current namespace which was `Baza\BlogBundle\Form`.

---

The funny looking Class `EntityManager50ecb6f979a07_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrin‌​e\ORM\EntityManager` is a Doctrine2 proxy class.

Since Symfony 2.1, calling `$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()` no lonoger results in a `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` but a proxy class which in fact behaves just like the original `EntityManager` and can be passed without problems.

Comment: In my example code I used `$this->em`. It seems you accidently used `$this->$em` (with a $ in front of `em`) which looks for a variable named `$em` and uses its value as the property name for `$this`. As you didn't define `$em` PHP tries to access `$this->null` (more or less). To access a property of an object use `$object->property` so in this case `$this->em`.

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol is needed to indicate that the argument is a service.  However, as you found out, @ trips up the yaml parser.  The solution is to use quotes.

```
services:
    filterType:
        class: Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

I remember it taking me a few hours to figure this out as well.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The error has changed to:`Argument 1 passed to ... filterType::__construct() must be an instance of Baza\BlogBundle\Form\EntityManager, instance of EntityManager50ec...919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given` I'm passing argument in my controller like this: `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); $form = $this->createForm(new filterType($em), $enquiry);` What am I missing?

Comment: The first error was saying that I didn't pass any arguments: `none given`, and now it's saying that passed argument is wrong: `instance of EntityManager50ec...919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given`. The second part of error message is different.

Comment: This is the full error message:`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType::__construct() must be an instance of Baza\BlogBundle\Form\EntityManager, instance of EntityManager50ecb6f979a07_546a8d27f194334ee012bfe64f629947b07e4919\__CG__\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\baza\src\Baza\BlogBundle\Controller\PageController.php on line 230 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\baza\src\Baza\BlogBundle\Form\filterType.php line 18`